# SSL : HTTP to HTTPS conversion error

Tags: linux, tomcat, ssl, https, truststore

I have generated the certificate and added to trust store using  the below commands

```
keytool -genkey -alias CERT-ALIAS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048  -validity 365 -keystore Certificate_Online
keytool -certreq -v -alias CERT-ALIAS -keystore Certificate_Online.jks -file Certificate_Online.csr
keytool  -export -alias CERT-ALIAS -file Certificate_Online.cer -keystore Certificate_Online
```

i modified my server.xml as below

server.xml:

```
<Connector  port="2222" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
keystoreFile="/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/Certificate_Online.jks" keystorePass="changeit" />
```

still when i try to open the link in the broswer 
it is showing This site can’t be reached ,ip refused to connect. please help me out . tried a lot but could find where the problem is.
thanks a lot in advance .

Comment: What server is this question about?

Comment: iam trying to establish a client server connection through tomcat 7.0.40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that this is not working is that the certificate is not trusted. You generated a Certificate Signing Request, but it does not appear to have been signed (by a Certificate Authority).

In order to get around this for testing you can add your certificate to your own trusted certificate store. In Linux you should be able to do this by using the keytool -import command in your JRE. Something like this:

```
keytool -import -file /jdk1.6.0_32/bin/Certificate_Online.cer -alias CERT-ALIAS -keystore "/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -storepass changeit
```

In Windows you can double click on the .cer file, click "Install Certificate" and place the certificate in the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" store.